# How to send the Unnecessary items to save procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, foreign-key-relationship

I a have table named "Document" in sql server and the same class in visual studio. I have some unnecessary property that should not fill in the program and some of them are foreign key field. if user do not fill the unnecessary items they will be null and when the save procedure is running it can not accept null value. (and the save error for foreign keys !) 
What should I do to fix this error ?

Comment: perhaps you should start by showing us what your code looks like..also if particular fields can not be null then you need to do one of two things alter the procedure to accept default values or add some validation in your code that will check for particular fields to make sure they are not null..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are not necessary then the easy answer is to allow those columns in the database to be null.

```sql
alter table dbo.[document] alter column [fk_column_name] int null;
```

The hard answer would be to re-evaluate your schema design because null values (especially foreign keys) can turn into painful issues later. [Why we shouldn't allow nulls](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5222/why-shouldnt-we-allow-nulls_)

Answer (score 0):

At my point of view you should solve this by changing the column to accept null values..

But if you don't want to do it, fill it with a default value. For example, if an int can't be null in my table, then I use "-1" as my default value and I'll know that everytime I see -1 is because it's suppose to be null (I emphasize that this is not the best way, but it will work)

on your code it would be something like:

```
if(myvar == null)  
{
  //your default value
  myvar = -1;
}
```